# Cannot download dependencies artifacts from FTP Maven Repository using the FTP protocol

Tags: maven, ftp, wagon

I have the following problem: 
I use for tests purposes a FTP server as repository.
All works fine to deploy (Upload) the different artifacts. 
As soon as I need to resolve and download artifacts dependencies previously uploaded on that repo, I get the following WARN:
[WARN] myrepo (ftp://ftp.myftpadress.fr/dev/M2Repo/, releases+snapshots) ignored (only S3, HTTP/S, and FILE are supported).
I cannot access the repository with the HTTP protocol.
So does wagon support the FTP protocol for downloading needed artifacts?

Here is my POM "Wagon" Section:

```
...
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
            <!-- I tried with older versions also-->
            <version>2.2</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>myrepo</id>
        <name>my Maven Repository</name>
        <url>ftp://ftp.myftpadress.fr/dev/M2Repo/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>myrepo</id>
        <name>my Maven Repository</name>
        <url>ftp://ftp.myftpadress.fr/dev/M2Repo/</url>
        <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>myrepo</id>
        <name>my Maven Repository</name>
        <url>ftp://ftp.myftpadress.fr/dev/M2Repo/</url>
        <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

I have also the needed infos in the settings.xml, it is OK because the artifact deployment works.

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>myrepo</id>
        <username>myuser</username>
        <password>mypassword</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

I use the following maven & Java versions:
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 03:44:56-0500)
Maven home: D:\maven\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin..
Java version: 1.7.0_09, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: D:\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\jre
Default locale: fr_CA, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

THANKS A LOT IN ADVANCE! And happy new year...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite think you can do that. Maven resolves it's dependencies via HTTP. You can upload them via different protocols such as FTP, SCP, HTTP and DAV, but it resolves them via HTTP/HTTPS.

Comment: Hi Carlspring, thanks for your answer. That is also my feeling. I will use then artifactory for my tests...

Comment: If you haven't picked an artifact repository, I would recommend Sonatype Nexus, but that's just a personal preference.

Comment: Hi I have setup a github repository for my first tests. It works perfectly. I will consider Sonatype in a second time. Thanks for this piece of advice.